# Creating a new user with FOSUserBundle fails

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to create a new user from the command line and get this error:

```
Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
in /vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php line 368
```

When trying to create a user by registering over the webinterface I get this:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'salt' cannot be null
```

Logging in with an already existing user works. Also updating a profile and changing the password. Just creating new users doesn't work.

I am using v 1.3.1 in a very plain setup and haven't found any solution yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Fixed!

I had a custom constructor method in my User entity. There I had forgotten to call the parent's constructor with `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it help someone. You can see this error when use bcrypt encoder.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'salt' cannot be null
```

To solve this issue just add mapping override for salt attribute in your User class (make it nullable)

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *  @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *      name="salt",
 *      column=@ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", nullable=true)
 *      )
 *  })
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
     ...
}
```

**OR:** don't forget update your schema. If error happend after composer update!

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```